# Разграничение доступа к записям в одной БД (таблице)

Tags: java, база-данных

Есть БД с набором таблиц, записи в которые создаются разными пользователями. Возможно ли реализовать доступ к данным так, чтобы каждый пользователь имел доступ (в том числе на чтение), только к тем записям, которые он сам создал. Если да, то как это лучше реализовать?  Можно ли это сделать средствами JAVA?
Речь идет о СУБД H2 и MySQL.

Comment: MySQL не имеет встроенной системы разграничения прав на уровне записи таблицы. Для использования штатных средств придётся для каждого пользователя создавать свою таблицу, а при необходимости объединить данные использовать UNION либо MERGE Engine. Либо отдавать данные хранимой процедурой, где реализовать логику предоставления пользователю только его данных - ввести в структуру поле пользователя, и отдавать ему только его данные. Можно организовать такое разграничение и на уровне скрипт-сервера (если таковой есть, конечно) - но это менее надёжно.

Comment: А если попробовать добавить поле user для каждой записи, реализовать связь один-ко-многим с таблицей пользователей (так как одну запись могут создавать несколько пользователей, по факту, если запись существует, то новая не создается, а пользователь добавляется в список "авторов"), и реализовать вывод с отбором по пользователям - это очень кривой способ?

Comment: *если запись существует, то новая не создается, а пользователь добавляется в список "авторов"* В этом случае любой пользователь будет иметь доступ к любой записи - достаточно попробовать её создать, и вот он уже "автор" с правами. *реализовать связь один-ко-многим с таблицей пользователей (так как одну запись могут создавать несколько пользователей* Вряд ли пользователь может создать только одну запись... так что много-ко-много.

Comment: "В этом случае любой пользователь будет иметь доступ к любой записи - достаточно попробовать её создать"        Да, об этом не подумал...  А если пойти на возможность создания одинаковых записей, которые будут отличаться только "автором" - это очень криво?  В принципе, ожидаемое количество таких записей не слишком большое.

Comment: Зависит от того, нужна ли синхронность изменения таких "псевдо-одной" записей. Если нет - нормальное решение, а если да - то мы возвращаемся к предыдущему случаю.

Comment: @Akina Нет, не нужна. В принципе, записи могут отличаться в одном - двух полях, а могут быть одинаковые.  Спасибо, не знаю, как оценить ответ.

Comment: доступ будет осуществляется только через клиента на java?

Comment: Да, только средствами Java (servlet)

Answer (score 0):

создать отдельную таблицу только с users ,  если у каждого будет что то уникальное и если у таблицы будет что то уникальное , что соответствует этим двум уникальностям ...  далее > каждый юзер может создавать таблицы как вам надо, но при создании будет стоять дэфолтное значение какой - то уникальности .. например создает первый юзер таблицу1 - дэфолтная уникальность 1 и заносится в таблицу1 .. если происходит редактирование какой то из таблиц , если соответствует тот уникальный ключ (который был задан для каждого пользователя) уникальному ключу этой таблице, если да - то редактируй , если нет то нет ..